# What is ablest navigators?

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning

What does this sentence means?

> The winds and waves are always on the side of the ablest navigators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word “able” means having *enough* of any necessary characteristics (strength, skill, permission, whatever is needed) to accomplish something.<sup>1</sup>

The word “ablest” is formed from “able” and the “-est” suffix, which indicates the superlative form: it is equivalent to “most able.” It isn’t used very often by today’s English speakers,<sup>2</sup> but it is certainly something you’ll see from time to time, particularly in older works.

In this case, “ablest navigator,” we have a pretty typical “adjective noun” construction: “ablest” describes the sort of “navigator” we’re looking for. This is, again, not something you see a lot in modern English—for whatever reason, “able” in any form is rarely used for “adjective noun” constructions today.<sup>3</sup>

So the “ablest navigator” is the person who *most* exhibits the qualities required to be a navigator, which I imagine are primarily training and experience.

1. <sub>Compare related words like “capable,” “ability,” and so on. It also appears as a suffix, “-able,” usually attached to a verb to create an adjective meaning “having the requisite characteristics to allow the verb to be performed upon it.”</sub>
2. <sub>Though I wouldn’t go so far as to call it *archaic* or anything.</sub>
3. <sub>Instead it is usually used with verbs of being, for example “I am able to X” to indicate that you have whatever is required to do X.</sub>

Comment: As an annex to KRyan's answer. The sentence means that more competent navigators are more successful in harnessing the elements - wind and waves - to their advantage.